# Align right icons in bootstrap buttons on a sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to align right the icon in a bootstrap button which in turn resides in a navbar on a left column.
I tried a dozen modifications in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/daq919ho/1/) fiddle.
Maybe `.btn-group` is not a good idea?

I can see in firebug that a `.btn-group` inside another `.btn-group` make my anchors to follow this rule:

```
.btn-group-justified > .btn-group .btn {
    width: 100%;
}
```

but on the other hand one `.btn-group` makes my anchors worse as they follow this one:

```
.btn-group-justified > .btn, .btn-group-justified > .btn-group {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    width: 1%;
}
```

Also, a `<button>` inside a `.navbar` behaves really strange!

In the jsfiddle the first button is inside two `.btn-group`s, the second one is inside one group class.
I've seen different solutions of the problem but none with buttons and collapsible panels inside a navbar.

Comment: In every viewport width I want my buttons to cover 100% minus the width of the icon.

Comment: viewport is the whole window.

Comment: every window is the same in every device, in every person? Think not!

Comment: My bad, I didn't see any indication of mobile devices mentioned...No, I still don't see it. Oops, silly me I forgot to use my mind reading hat , oh wait a minute they haven't been invented yet. I'm afraid we'll have to do it the old fashioned way and actually post the fact that you are developing for mobile devices.

Comment: well, let the readers vote then!

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote you, although that is an indicator that perhaps you should improve your question by adding a tag associated with subjects concerning mobile development aspects.

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate my solution [there](https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/daq919ho/2/).

I simply re-implement an old solution to this problem (I like to call it the top-bar window alignment problem):

I gave to an external wrapper this styles:

```
.sidebar-btn {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}
```

and to an internal one:

```
.sidebar-btn > * {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Now, you can see the second `<a>` to be pushed on the right edge by giving a specific width:

```
.sidebar-btn > *:nth-child(2) {
   width: 14px;
}
```

This solution works regardless of bootstrap.
Some cosmetic corrections though should be done to ease bootstrap's styling as can be seen at the final code.

Comment: An updated version with less markup where the button is actually one consisting with text + icon: https://jsfiddle.net/daq919ho/3/